# Is the phrase "Discontinuance of service" mainly use as a legal term?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-choice, legalese

[From Lawinsider](https://www.lawinsider.com/dictionary/discontinuance-of-service#:%7E:text=Discontinuance%20of%20service%20means%20a,voluntarily%20requested%20by%20a%20customer.)

> Discontinuance of service or "Discontinuance" means cessation of service not requested by a Customer; "Distribution facilities" means terminal poles, manholes, feeder lines, service lines, switch gear, pole-mounted,

> Discontinuance of service means the intentional cessation of basic local exchange service by a LEC not voluntarily requested by a customer.

> Discontinuance of service means formal enforcement action taken against a non-compliant user, wherein the non-compliant user's water and/or wastewater service is shutdown or otherwise discontinued. Drought means a combination of many complex factors acting and interacting with the environment resulting in water supplies not being replenished normally. In simple terms, a drought occurs when existing water supplies cannot meet established demands for a period of time. Drought alert, drought critical, drought watch, no drought are references to drought alerts identified in the City of Henderson's adopted Southern Nevada Water Authority (SNWA) Drought Response Plan.

From the above definition, it seems to me the phrase "discontinuance of service" is use by an authority to terminate a service forcefully.

If we use the phrase "discontinuance of service" in a non-legal context, will it be interpreted as the service is forcefully terminated by the provider?

I would like to express the customer discontinued the service, not forcefully terminated by the provider. It is not a legal context but would like to sound more formal. Are the following sentences acceptable?

For e.g.

1. I have returned the gym membership pass upon discontinuance of service.
2. I have returned the gym membership pass upon discontinuing the service.
3. They continue to invoice us despite our discontinuance of service last month.
4. They continue to invoice us despite we have discontinued the service last month.

Comment: The definitions you quoted should make it clear that "discontinue" doesn't apply when customers stop the service. The word you want is "cancel".

Comment: @gotube Ahh... yes. Cancel!! It never crossed my mind! Thank you!

Comment: Yes... Did you mean something different? That your membership has ended, that you've allowed it to lapse?

Comment: @gotube yes. In the context where service is off-contract and can be stopped/discontinued without any obligations.

Comment: I don't understand. How can you have a membership without a contract? How could you continue using a gym membership after the contract had expired??

Comment: @gotube hmm...hourly, daily, weekly or monthly payment? Is it a must to have a contract to use gym? From I am, it doesn't require one. Anyway, that's only an example sentence. Thanks